# Python writing filenames with variables

Tags: python, xml

I am creating XML files for each iteration and values of the three parameters in this code:

```
def BOFunc():
fileCount = 1
q = 20
m=1
for child in root.iter('Traces'):
    child.find('TS')
    child.find('TW')
    for ts in frange(3,12.75,0.25):
        child.set('TS',str(ts))
        for tw in frange(3,12.75,0.25):
                child.set('TW',str(tw))
                for child2 in root.iter('Stackup'):
                    child2.find('core_h')
                    for h in frange(2,4,0.5):
                        for child3 in root.iter('Definition'):                        
                            child3.set('modelname', 'Output{}.xml'.format(fileCount))
                            child2.set('core_h',str(h))
                            tree.write('C:\Users\Aravind_Sampathkumar\Desktop\IMLC\BO\Output{}.xml'.format(fileCount))
                            D = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=(fileCount,))
                            D.start()
                            if m%5 == 0:
                                D.join()
                            fileCount += 1
                            q +=20
                            m +=1
```

Once it is run it creates files named `Output1.xml`, `Output2.xml`, and so on till the max value of the variable `fileCount`.

Is there a way I can create the same XML files with the name: variable_name-Value?
For example: `if TW = 3, TS = 4 and core_h = 2`, the file name would be `TW_3-TS_4-core_h_2.xml`.

Comment: changing your loop variable names from i, j and k might help if they're really 'ts', 'tw' and 'core_h'. Also you seem to set TW to i when maybe it should be set to k?

Comment: Noted. Thanks didn't spot that! And yes I will make that edit now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate the variables values in a string

```
filename = "TW_" + str(TW) + "-TS_" + str(TS) + "-core_h_" + str(h) + ".xml"
```

Comment: `tree.write('C:\Users\Aravind_Sampathkumar\Desktop\IMLC\BO\' + filename)`

Comment: `filename = "TW_{tw}-TS_{ts}-core_h_{h}.xml".format(tw=tw, ts=ts, h=h)` is an alternative way to write this that you may or may not find more readable.